# Transformation of coordinates between 2 basis for a tensor of rank 2

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

In the context of General relativity and tensor calculus, I would like to know where is my error in the following demo :

We can start with $u$ and $u'$ curvilinear coordinates :

$$\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial u^i} ; \quad \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\prime}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial u^{\prime k}}$$

The transformation follows :

$$\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\prime}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial u^{\prime k}}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial u^i} \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial u^{\prime k}}=\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{i}} \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial u^{\prime k}}$$

So we define :

(a) $\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{i}}=A_i^{\prime k} \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\prime}$;
(b) $\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\prime}=A_k^i \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{i}}$

and :

(a) $A_i^{\prime k}=\frac{\partial u^{\prime k}}{\partial u^i}$
(b) $A_k^i=\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial u^{\prime k}}$

This way, we can write :

$$e'_k.e'_l = g'_{kl} = A_k^i A_l^j e_i.e_j = A_k^i A_l^j g_{ij}$$

Finally, we would have :

$$g'_{kl} = A_k^i A_l^j g_{ij}$$

and finally (fixed) :

$$g'_{kl} = \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial u^{\prime k}}\,\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial u^{\prime l}} g_{ij}$$

is it correct ?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769910/2451

Comment: The equation$$\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial u^i} $$seems off. How do you define the RHS? I think that one would usually write$$\mathbf{e}_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i} $$instead (I don't like this notation, but it is very common). Note that each $\mathbf{e}_i$ constitutes a vector field.

Comment: @Filippo . Yes, you're right, your notation is the most common used. In my notation, $\textbf{M}$ represent the vector $\textbf{OM}$. By the way, could we write : 

$g^{ik}\mathbf{e}_i=g^{ik}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial u_k}$ ? I have always had difficulties with the notation : $g^{ik}\partial_i = \partial^k$ . Regards

Comment: "In my notation" - I should warn you that this only makes sense in the context of an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space), where you can indeed associate a vector to each pair of points.

Comment: "By the way, could we write" - Since $e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}$, you are asking whether $g^{ik}e_i=e_k$. But this equation is clearly not correct in general.

Comment: "I have always had difficulties with the notation" - If we interpret $(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n)$ as a basis, then $(\partial^1,\ldots,\partial ^n)$ would be the dual basis, so the equation $g^{ik}\partial_i = \partial^k$ doesn't make sense (you are equating a vector and a co-vector).

Comment: What you probably read is that $g^{ik}v_i=v^k$ for a vector $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct?

Yes, the equation
$$g'_{kl} = \dfrac{\partial u^i}{\partial u^{\prime k}}\,\dfrac{\partial u^j}{\partial u^{\prime l}} g_{ij}$$
is correct. Here is a slightly different derivation using the dual basis:
$$\tilde g_{ij}=g(\tilde e_i,\tilde e_j)=g(e_ke^k\tilde e_i,e_le^l\tilde e_j)=e^k\tilde e_ie^l\tilde e_jg(e_k,e_l)=e^k\tilde e_ie^l\tilde e_jg_{kl}$$
To finally obtain your equation, we simply note that
$$e^i=\mathrm du{}^i=\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial \tilde u^k}\mathrm d \tilde u^k=\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial \tilde u^k}\tilde e^k$$
and hence
$$e^k\tilde e_i=\frac{\partial u^k}{\partial \tilde u^l} \underbrace{\tilde e^l\tilde e_i}_{=\delta^l{}_i}=\frac{\partial u^k}{\partial \tilde u^i}$$